# jQuery loop checkboxes and tick ones which id exists in an array of number

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I'm working on a script which will get a JSON array of id's. Based on the results, I then loop over all the checkboxes on the page and check the boxes where the id exists in the JSON array.

The checkboxes are named like so name="name[id]" id="name[id]"

How do I loop the checkboxes and determine if the id (between [ and ] ) exists in the JSON array?

Comment: JSON is not array, it's object.

Comment: Okay, so I get the following items back for example:

Comment: @Māris Kiseļovs - JSON is text that can be parsed into the appropriate data type for the given language. In javascript, an Array or an Object. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick is correct, it's not valid to have `[` and `]` in an attribute.  Assuming your HTML looks something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name3" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name4" /><br/>
```

You could use the [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
var ids = new Array();
ids[0] = 1;
ids[1] = 3;

$.each(ids, function(index, value) {
    $("input[name$='name" + value + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't valid to have `[` and `]` in an HTML4 ID attribute.

That said, you could do a `.filter()` to check each item for the ID in the array:

```
var array; //holds the Array from the JSON

$(':checkbox').filter(function() {
    var id = this.id.slice( this.id.indexOf('[') + 1, -1 );
    return $.inArray( id, array ) > -1;
})
  .attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: @user - As long as the JSON is valid and is properly parsed after it is received, then it will be just another javascript Array, so yes, it should work the same. :o)